# Can't integrate AdMob in my app (Android Studio)

Tags: android, admob, build.gradle

I need to implement AdMob in my project, so first I wanted to set up Google Play Services
Did everything as on official site:
-Download latest (4.4.52) Google Play Services in SDK manager
-In build.gradle in dependencies added

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
```

Got this error when sync project:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52.
>        Required by:
>            MyApplication:app:unspecified

Please, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your build.gradle and make sure that the mavenCentral reposority is included. Your file should look something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

     buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
      }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
}
```

Comment: mavenCentral reposority is included, but still the same error

Comment: Okay. Please check take a look in your SDK Manager and check if the Google Reposority and Android Support Reposority are installed. Note that the Android Build Tools must be installed too and the Revision Number must be entered in your build.gradle file (e.g. buildToolsVersion "19.1")

Comment: OH Yeah! Google Repository did fix it! Thanx a lot!